Illustrator: How can I quickly and precisely scale an object up or down?
In InDesign which I use 80% of the time as a Designer, I find it incredibly easy to scale an object up or down by using the Scale X Percentage function which is easily accessible in the Application Bar when the Advanced Workspace is enabled:

I use it hundreds of times a day, it's especially convenient since you can use the SHIFT key to scale in 10% increments.
Sometimes I use Illustrator. And the precise and frequent scaling of objects is always a more complicated workflow.

In its Application Bar, there is no way to scale a selected object in percentages. One can insert point or pixels values in the Transform boxes, but that's about it. The list of controls you can add to Illustrator is very limited, compared to the controls you can add in InDesign.

It seems the only way I can scale objects would be to:

Select the object
Click Object in the Object Menu
Click Scale in the Transform Sub-menu
In the window that pops up, change the scale, eyeball the results, and click OK
(While the Transform window is open, I am unable to access the Artboard to move or arrange items)
Repeat all this process for each object I want to scale.

Illustrator has been around for almost 40 years.
Am I missing something, a feature that would allow me to scale an object by percentage increments in one or two clicks only, without having to go into a window that locks me out of being able to see and interact with my Artboard?

Eh . . . you can type percentages directly into the width or height fields. No need to go into the transform sub-menu.

This is really a catch22 for Adobe with Illustrator. If they made the Transform Panel fields default to work in a relative manner (%) then users would complain they couldn't use any precise units. Of course, they could add an option to change how the panel displays measurements, but I wouldn't hold my breath for that.
Note that you can use % in those w and h fields, they just aren't the default view. If you input w: [ 50% ] the selection will scale to 50% width, then show the new numerical unit value based on that transformation. You actually can use any value in those fields, %, px, pt, p, in, cm, mm, etc. If the desire is to use a unit different than the current unit for the document, you have to include the unit in the value - 2in, 2cm, 2pt, 2p0, 2mm, 2px, 2%, etc. And it is possible to do math within the fields as well... i.e. 150%/2 will result in 75% being used, or 2in*2 will result in 4 inches.
But your observations are accurate. It's not possible to set a % in the transform fields, then change the % with arrow keys. The Transform fields always go back to displaying a unit value using the measurement unit for the document.
If you want to always use relative amounts (%), then the Scale Tool may be better.
A few options....

Make the Transform Panel visible in the UI rather than using the
Popup panel (Window > Transform)
With art selected, double-click the Scale tool in the toolbar (transform origin is always the center of selection).
Tap s on the keyboard (selects Scale Tool), then option/alt click the artwork.. same as #2 essentially. However, where you click sets the transform origin.

In all fields.. shift-up/down-arrow will increment by 10, wether it's % or a unit.. shift = 10 steps.
If I understand correctly, you could select art, double-click the Scale tool, shift-arrow, and enter when you're happy. The Scale dialog will retain the Uniform/Nonuniform selection from its last use. And the dialog should put the focus on the first value field, you really should not need to click inside the dialog at all once you've set the Uniform/Nonuniform option. (but like everywhere, Tab will also move to other fields within the dialog and it's smart enough to set the Uniform option if that field is focused.)

Also possible to add a transform effect to an object in the appearance panel. From there you can actually use percentages, and increase or decrease them with the up and down arrow keys.

That's a good point @BillyKerr - And.. if you set up Graphic Styles for various percentages using an Effect, it could just be a single click after that.

No such button available without add-ons. There should be visible near the width and height info fields inc and dec buttons which add or subtract one used unit, but not a percentage.
Select an object, type its new size as percents to the width field in the info bar. If you have proportional size link ON, you need only input the new width or the new height.
For example to increase the size by 10% only type 110% to the width field. It needs also pressing the enter or clicking elsewhere.
If you must apply the same percentage to several objects it's easiest to use the Transform > Scale dialog. Of course, you can also paste the percentage to the info bar width or height field.
